# Turning off the blue status LED on the logitech C920 usb camera?

Tags: usb, camera

I am playing around with the [logitech c920](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/hd-pro-webcam-c920) connected to a Raspberry Pi 4 and being used as a baby monitor. Hence I would like to turn off the blue status light if possible; preferably via unix command line.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually found the answer in [this blog](http://www.togaware.com/linux/survivor/Video_Camera.html). It might work with other logitech cameras too.

```
sudo apt-get install uvcdynctrl
sudo uvcdynctrl -i /usr/share/uvcdynctrl/data/046d/logitech.xml

# LED off
uvcdynctrl -s 'LED1 Mode' 0
# LED on
uvcdynctrl -s 'LED1 Mode' 1
# LED blinking
uvcdynctrl -s 'LED1 Mode' 2
# LED auto mode
uvcdynctrl -s 'LED1 Mode' 3
```